# How to merge two projects (.csproj) of Winforms in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, merge, migration

I have a desktop application that runs in collaboration with the other windows applications. For better understand, please have a look at the following layout.

[image]

All the applications Quiz Game, A, B, C, and D, are independent EXEs and I have their .csproj projects with me. What I want to do is, merge them all so that I don't have to rely on multiple EXEs but one.

**Is there anyone who has done this before, or knows about any utility/plugin/extension/code?**

I tried the following tool, but turns out it is too complicated and didn't work out.
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=slntools

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this.  You can't just _merge two projects_.  You can cherry pick files from one project, copy them to the other project's folder and then add them to the first project and then twiddle your code to call them.  Or, you can take each of your "sub projects" and make them a "class library".  Have each of them implement an interface, and then either have the main application statically load them (via project references) or via some plug-in mechanism.  If it were me, I'd probably use a common Interface and static loading (unless plug-in was desirable)

Comment: Do you have the `.csproj` files with you or just the `.exe` files?

Comment: @preciousbetine, I do have .csproj with me.

Comment: @Flydog57 thank you for your response. Well, I tried cherry picking before putting this question, but it is very time-consuming as each project has its own namespaces, resources, and settings. However, I do consider this as my last option. Furthermore, I don't understand the concept of converting Windows .csprojs to the class library. Can you please elaborate, it seems interesting?

Comment: You should merge all the project files into one solution. Then add references to the other projects from your main project.

Comment: @preciousbetine, that is what I am currently doing. When I deploy the application, all the .csproj projects (A, B, C, D) get compiled and their EXEs are further being used by Quiz Game application. I think you didn't understand my question properly. I want to merge multiple .csproj projects into one .csproj file. Not all .csproj files to one solution. But, thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't think that is possible thing to do automatically . To do that, you will have to manually copy all the forms and code from the other csproj files into your main project file.

Comment: Create new projects for each of your "exe" projects.  However, make them "class libraries" (i.e., DLLs).  Copy the code from the EXE projects to your new projects, adding the files to the new project.  Don't include Program.cs.  Now comes the hard part.  Create yet another (class lib) project that includes only the definition of an interface that you will use to invoke each of your forms.  In each class new class lib project implement that interface (in a way that will start up your form).  Put in some factory pattern stuff to start things up.  Ran out of space in comments

Comment: @Flydog57 I really enjoyed your response and liked the ending... lol. However, on a serious note, I think it would be a way to much work than cherrypicking. Because, there are not just 4-5 projects that as I exemplified here, but 30+. I have to convert them into one. Changing the nature of the projects would require a lot of regression testings. Well, all these application are running for over 10-15 years. But, I will still consider it and see the feasibility. Thanks for your response. Have a good one.

Comment: Create a single solution containing all the projects. Select the one which contains the main entry form. Set it as startup project. Add reference other projects to the main project. By using the namespace of each project, you have access to all it's public forms.

Comment: But, you need to change your projects from EXEs to class libraries, and you need to create a way to fire up the form from a "main-ish" function in each class library.  My suggestion was to have all your new class library's have a main-like class/method that implements a common interface.  Maybe I'll throw something together this weekend.